# sql query speed. Time response to long

Tags: mysql, time, response

I have problem with my mysl query. Response time is to long. My query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    t.id,
    l.id_produkt_lista,
    z.nr_zam,
    k.nazwa_fv,
    p.nazwa,
    p.opis,
    p.data_realizacji,
    CONCAT(t.d_graf,'</br>', IF(t.D_d_graf IS NOT NULL,
        DATE_FORMAT(t.D_d_graf, "%d-%m-%Y"),"")),
    CONCAT(t.d_druk,'</br>', IF(t.D_d_druk IS NOT NULL,
        DATE_FORMAT(t.D_d_druk, "%d-%m-%Y"),"")),
    CONCAT(t.d_zgrz,'</br>', IF(t.D_d_zgrz IS NOT NULL,
        DATE_FORMAT(t.D_d_zgrz, "%d-%m-%Y"),""))
    FROM zamowienie_produkt_lista l
    JOIN zamowienia_zamowienie z ON (l.id_zamowienie = z.id_zamowienie) 
    JOIN zamowienia_produkt p    ON (l.id_produkt = p.id_produkt) 
    JOIN zamowienia_prac_tmp t   ON (l.id_produkt = t.id_produkt) 
    JOIN zamowienia_klient k     ON (z.id_klient = k.id_klient)
    WHERE TRUE
      AND id_typ_produkt = '1'
      AND z.archiwum = 0
    ORDER BY t.id
```

When I use it in phpmyadmin I have to wait about 10 second

Comment: What `WHERE TRUE` do?

Comment: Nothing but it's not a problem with this

Comment: Please show your schema, existing indexes and output of your query under `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: Is there an index on id_typ_produkt? is there one on z.archiwum? Are there indexes on all the JOIN columns?

Comment: Which table column `id_typ_produkt` belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id_typ_produkt` belongs to table `zamowienie_produkt_lista`, creating following indexes should help:

```
CREATE INDEX p_1_idx ON zamowienie_produkt_lista
    (id_produkt, id_typ_produkt);

CREATE INDEX z_1_idx ON zamowienia_zamowienie
    (id_zamowienie, archiwum);
```

You should also make sure that indexes on all `*_id` fields for all other joined tables exist.